# Replace squared brackets with div tags

Tags: php

Can someone please help me with this: 
For example I have this string:

```
"
[row]
[col-md-6 col-lg-3]
Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet... And the rest of the text
[/col]
[/row]
"
```

Is there any way in PHP to replace this squared brackets with 
`<div class="<some_dynamic_tags>">`
Here's some of my code. It only works for closing tags ( [/col], [/row]). Still don't know how to solve this problem for opening tags.

```
class Html extends BaseHtml
{
    public static function containsChar($haystack, $needle)
    {
        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
        if ($pos === false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static function doShortcode($string)
    {
        if (Html::containsChar($string, '/'))
        {
            // This is a closing tag
            return '</div>';
        }
        else
        {
            // This is an opening tag

        }
    }

    public static function bootstrapShortcode($text)
    {
        preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);

        $htmlText = $matches[1];
        echo nl2br($text) . '<br>';
        foreach ($htmlText as $val) {
            var_dump(Html::doShortcode($val));
        }
        return $htmlText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that

```
<?php
 echo "<div class='yourClass'>'{$yourVariable}'</div>"; 
?>

or

<?php
 echo '<div class="yourClass">"{$yourVariable}"</div>';
?>
```

Depends what you need.

Comment: I don't think you correctly interpreted what Marko was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of

```
    return '<div class="'.substr($string, 1, strlen($string) - 2).'">';
```

When `$string` is `"[col-md-6]"`, `<div class="col-md-6">` is returned.